# Is there a standard secure xmlreader class that is proof to various dos attacks?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xmlreader

I can always start to write my own, but i'd rather not have to maintain it reactivley. Although it may make an interesting learning experience.

So I am looking for a `XmlReader` class that has been proofed against various dos attacks (dtd, element depth, cross domain nastiness etc).

Anybody have any ideas?
My only real reource atm is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx

Comment: I've been looking into similar for PHP, as it happens. From what I can tell, if you don't need entities, just remove them - and that protects against both XML bombs as well as local file stealing. Also, ensure that the doctype points at a trusted DTD. Maintaining something to do those two things should be quite easy, unless you specifically need entities (I believe I can strip them out in my case).

Comment: Yeah I agree, although at the time of writing this I was uninformed as to whether I could get away without entities. I can so life is a LOT simpler!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use XmlReader.Create to create your reader DTD processing will be disabled by default so you should not be vulnerable to DTD attacks (note that this is not true for XmlTextReader where DTD processing is enabled by default - for more details see a [blog post I wrote](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using.aspx) and comments). For element Depth - I don't think XmlReader really cares - it is just a state machine that will record finding a nested element in the Depth property.